# PostgreSQL Function that updates a specific column of a row

Tags: postgresql, sql-function, sql-variant

I am trying to make a function which calls a specific data from the table but why it's showing column doesn't exist even tho its on database .

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."updateDB"(IN userid bigint DEFAULT 00000, OUT uinfo json, IN clname text DEFAULT info)
RETURNS json
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT clname into uinfo 
    FROM public.users 
    WHERE uid = userid;
END;
$BODY$;
```

but when i try to call it , it shows this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3a6.png)
here i tried to make info default so this error occurs . If i don't make anything default and run the function from code , it shows that error again.

Answer (score 1):

You need quote your text otherwise postgres think you are referring to a column

```
IN clname text DEFAULT 'info'
```

Comment: i tried that but if i run  `select selectDB("info",23435353335)`   from code , this error occurs
`ERROR:  column "info" does not exist
LINE 1: select selectDB(info,23435353335)
                        ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 17`

Comment: `'info'` is a string value `"info"` is a column name. Try  `selectDB('info',23435353335)`. But I dont think that will give you what you want. that only will return `'info'` as result

Comment: btw your function is called `updteDB` not `selectDB`